# Using the * operator in a mysql FULLTEXT seach in order to get partial matches for multiple words

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have the following query (just learning fulltext searches):

**SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (`bio`, `bio2`, `bio3`) AGAINST ('smok each' IN BOOLEAN MODE)**

How can I use the "*" operator in a way that the above query will return:

- fields that contain the words: smoke, smoking ...,
- fields that contain the words: teach, teacher, ...

So I need partial matches... and the most important thing is the match can be in every position of the word: beginning, middle, end - for example the word "each" would match **teach** and **eachother**

Ty

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many fields you want to search through, wouldn't this work:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [bio] LIKE '%smok%' OR [bio] LIKE '%each%' OR [bio2] LIKE '%smok%' OR [bio2] LIKE '%each%'... etc
```